# How to import private key with passprhase from PEM file

Tags: c++, ssl, cryptoapi

I trying to load a private key from a PEM file using CryptStringToBinary and CryptDecodeObjectEx, that works fine when the private key is not password protected, but it doesn't work when the key is password protected.

```
if(!CryptStringToBinary(buffer.get(), length, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(outBuffer.get()),
                        &outLength, 0, 0))
{
    cerr << "CryptStringToBinary Error: " << GetLastError();
    return -1;
}

DWORD keyBlobLength = 0;
CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO* keyBlob = 0;

if(!CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO, 
                        reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(outBuffer.get()), 
                        outLength, CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG, 0, &keyBlob, &keyBlobLength))
{
    cerr << "CryptDecodeObjectEx Error:\n" << GetLastError();
    return -1;
}
```

Any ideas how to decrypt the PEM file using the password? I need to use WinCrypt not openssl.